# Unable to connect Wamp MySQL database to Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have tried so many different IP Addresses as well as using 127.0.0.0 and my own computer IP Address, however when I run my program and try to register it contacts the server and then it suddenly stops and it says that the app name has stopped working. Please could you help me or give me a helping hand as I have been stuck on this issue for three days.

I have created a folder in wamp/www/ folder called bradvisor_login_api, this folder has three files and one of the file is for the config.php file which I have listed below. phpMyAdmin account does not have a password it only has username which is root.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue, I have pasted my config.php file and some of my java file where it shows the connection.

**Config.PHP File**

```
<?php

/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB_DATABASE", "bradvisor_login_api");
?>
```

**Java connection file**

```
//URL of the PHP API


   private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.0.8:80/bradvisor_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://192.168.0.8:80/bradvisor_login_api/";
    private static String forpassURL = "http://192.168.0.8:80/bradvisor_login_api/";
    private static String chgpassURL = "http://192.168.0.8:80/bradvisor_login_api/";
```

**httpd.conf File**

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

**Error Logcat**

```
  07-02 20:02:42.163    2269-2526/com.brad.visor E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-02 20:02:42.163    2269-2526/com.brad.visor E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
07-02 20:02:42.194    2269-2269/com.brad.visor E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.brad.visor, PID: 2269
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.brad.visor.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:232)
            at com.brad.visor.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:189)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**Register.java File:**

```
private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
{

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {

if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
------------------------------------------
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");

                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                         **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);

                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

Comment: What is the error from logcat?

Comment: error catlog added, please help me.

Comment: That tells you what's going on.  What is Register.java line 232?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with htis f

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this file, however something is wrong with my database connection.

Comment: Do you mean the PHP server has a database connection problem?  I can't help you with that, but either way your android app has a problem.  It should not crash even if the PHP service fails or is inacessible.

Comment: Yhes, the php does have a database connection problem, the android app is fine it does not have a problem the reason it shows that line is that is when it connects to the database. I have wamp server and I am using phpmyadmin. I have created php index.php file in www folder. I use no password as I log in without a password and my username is root. Could you please give me your email so that I am able to give you my files in order for you to look at them and check what is wrong.

Comment: I have now added register.java file where it brings up the error, however it looks fine and I know that its a problem with the database connection.

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP so I can't help you there.  But I repeat, your Android app is not fine.  It crashes when the PHP service can't connect to the database.  That is bad.  It should be able to handle that situation without crashing.

Comment: Hi Nasch, I know what my error is that I have lots of deprecated methods. I have posted my JSONParser.java class which is the connection class. could you please rewrite and change the deprecated methods for me.

Comment: The Deprecated methods are BasicNameValuePair in the userfuction.java file. I get this error  'org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair' is deprecated and in the JSONParser.java I have more deprecated methods like (ClientProtocolException). Could you please rewrite the code without the deprecated methods.

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're warnings.  It's just a recommendation to use whatever replaces them.  They will not cause null pointer exceptions.

Comment: nasch could you please advise what shall i do to find the errors.

Comment: What errors?  If you mean the deprecation messages, they're not errors. If you mean the NullPointerException, the stack trace shows you exactly where it is.  If you mean in the PHP, I can't help you.  If you mean something else, please explain.

Comment: I have two errors in my code which I have highlighted in bold, could you please help me.

Comment: I get an error where it says if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { and private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask. please advise?.

Answer (score 0):

From your error log:
"Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"
What is the page you are requesting, and can you post its contents in the question.

As far as I can tell from the error log, the input is not parse-able. This seems to be the case when you receive an response as HTML (where the breakrow is the < br /> indicator, but on strings, they could be several, as \0 for instance.
It does seems that when parsing, the content is read as a single variable, and fails to buffer the whole response in the variable, then, that failed object becomes null, and you make an operation on it. (thus failing, and getting the logged error)

Comment: Bonatti, I have now added the Register.java file where it shows the two errors and I have made the error text line in bold.. could you please help and rewrite the code for me.

Comment: From your error log: Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).... this means you are sending the user and password, and that they are wrong. Also, I highly recommend using the [MSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) connection, instead of the deprecated msql

Comment: I dont have a password for root as the username for mysql is root and password is left blank so what shall  I put in the config,php file for the password section is define("DB_PASSWORD", "root"); fine or shall I use define("DB_PASSWORD", "");. Could you please advise?.

Comment: Again, please read about <b>MSQLI</b>. The php help page will show you HOW to create the connection. You might want to try that connection separatedly (and perhaps test with a simple SELECT * FROM 'a table name here'. Post the results). Then on your application, test the desired operation.,

Comment: Could you please check now as I have changed what you have told me and now i get different errors on the catlog could you please advise.

Comment: James. You have a null pointer exception. What does that mean? It means you performed an operation in an object that isnt instantiated yet. You have "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of" That could mean that the first letter in the variable name is NONE, and then, the system cannot assign a symbol to it. What you must do now, is go to the function that is triggering the error, and send the object along it.

Comment: could you advise what I need to do, Do I need to check my register.java file or JSON.java file.

Comment: You need to check what part of the program is causing the null pointer.For that, check (in the error log), what line caused the issue, and check that EVERY part of that line is correct. This likely means that you have an error generating another, test that line with each part separated, and check what is failing.

Comment: It says the following below.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.brad.visor.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:232)
            at com.brad.visor.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:189)

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio you have to put 10.0.2.2 as IP. It's the ip Android Studio use for localhost connection.